# Why does one "stand there like a lemon"?

Tags: slang, catch-phrases

I was standing around like a lemon the other day (meaning, standing doing nothing when I ought to have been a little more active) when it occurred to me to wonder, why does one *stand there like a lemon*? Does anyone know the origin of this term?

I know that when you buy a poor-quality car it is said to be a *lemon*. Why does this particular fruit have such negative connotations?

Comment: For the record - I've NEVER HEARD "stand around like a lemon."

Comment: @Joe Blow: [This](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=there+like+a+lemon&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) NGram for **"there like a lemon"** finds over 200 results, almost all of which are preceded by some variant of "stand" or "sit". I think the meaning is more about *being kept waiting with nothing to occupy oneself*, rather than *being idle or lazy*, though.

Comment: It's curious that the same expression is used in Italian, where _startene lì come un limone_ is used ("stand there like a lemon"). It's normally used in sentences such as _non startene lì come un limone_ ("don't stand there like a lemon").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe its origin will explain it pretty much.

It came from "Standing around like a lost lemon". Phrase Finder [here:](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/18/messages/658.html)

> Standing around like a lost lemon" is cited in Eric Partridge, "A Dictionary of Catch Phrases American and British" as a "more ladylike version" of "standing about like a spare prick at a wedding," defined as "unwanted, useless, idle, esp. with a hint of painfully embarrassed superfluity."

The reason "lemon" is used here, is because "lemon" in [slang means :](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lemon)

> slang  a person or thing considered to be useless or defective

The reason "lemon" has a negative connotation could possibly [be because:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lemon)

> "worthless thing," 1909, Amer.Eng. slang; from lemon (1), perhaps via criminal slang sense of "a person who is a loser, a simpleton," which is perhaps from the notion of someone a sharper can "suck the juice out of." A pool hall hustle was called a lemon game  (1908); while to hand someone a lemon  was British slang (1906) for "to pass off a sub-standard article as a good one." Or it simply may be a metaphor for something which "leaves a bad taste in one's mouth."

Comment: Ham - there's also the weird phrase "Until the pips squeak..." which (probably) started off in relation to squeezing lemons.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly an *origin* or *first use*, but [here's](http://books.google.com/books?id=44MEAAAAYAAJ&q=%22there%20like%20a%20lemon%22&dq=%22there%20like%20a%20lemon%22&hl=en&ei=occRTta_EoiX8QOez8zUDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA) the earliest usage I could find.

On being questioned about what was meant, the speaker there expanded by saying *"kind of soppy"*. I agree with the hearer, who replied that this particular metaphorical usage didn't *seem very witty or telling*.

Having said that, the expression did start to get used more often in the 1980s. Still only a couple of hundred usages in [this](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=there%20like%20a%20lemon&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) NGram for **there like a lemon**, but almost all of them are preceded by some variant of the verbs **stand** or **sit**.

In most cases the emphasis is on *being kept waiting, with nothing to occupy one's time*, rather than OP's implied *voluntarily choosing to be idle*. The implication being that the subject is unable to do anything about the enforced waiting.

I do not believe this particular usage owes much if anything to the (originally British) slang meaning of a *lemon* as a poor-quality troublesome purchase (normally a car). [Here's](http://books.google.com/books?id=jiE4AAAAMAAJ&q=%22there%20like%20a%20lemon%22&dq=%22there%20like%20a%20lemon%22&hl=en&ei=28oRTuu3FcSw8gO2o63LDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg) the second earliest usage I could find, which again defines the expression in terms of soppiness/ineffectuality. The most common thing done with lemons is to **squeeze** them; the the metaphorical usage alludes to the fact that we don't expect lemons to resist such treatment.